# How to Subtract the result of two Django Queries?

Tags: python, django

in my View.py

```
def reset(request):

    Result = [(Contact.objects.all().count()] - [(Subscriber.objects.all().count()]
    return HttpResponse(Result)
```

I want to Subtract these two queries,but it did not work.....

Comment: I don't understand why you've put those two counts into separate lists. Why not just directly subtract one from the other?

Comment: Daniel answer which is posted by Addi star solved my Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by this way :

```
 Contact.objects.all().count() - Subscriber.objects.all().count()
```

now you can easily `subtract` . i have edited the code. Please have a look